# Reusing a VertexBuffer or make new VertexBuffer object?

Tags: directx, 2d, vertex-buffer, directx-10

I'm trying to render bitmap fonts in directX10 at the moment, and I want to do this as efficiently as possible. I'm having a hard time getting a start on my design because of this question though.

So should I reuse a single VertexBuffer or make multiple VertexBuffer objects?

Currently I allocate one dynamic VertexBuffer per Quad object in my program. This way I wouldn't have to map/unmap a VertexBuffer if nothing moves on my screen. For fonts I can implement a similar method on where I allocate one buffer per text box, or something similar.

After searching I read about reusing a single VertexBuffer for all objects. Vertex caching came up also. What is the advantage/disadvantage of this, and is it faster than my previous method?

For last, is there any other method I should look into rendering many 2d quads in the screen?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single dynamic Vertex Buffer with the proper combinations of DISCARD and NO_OVERWRITE is the best way to handle this kind of dynamic submission. The driver will perform buffer renaming with DISCARD to minimize GPU stalls.

This is the mechanism used by SpriteBatch/SpriteFont and PrimitiveBatch in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929). You can check that source for details, and if really needed you could adopt it to Direct3D 10.x. Of course, moving to Direct3D 11 is probably the better choice.